# Query again same entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem regarding querying objects twice. I mean I have a situation like this:

1. In the site header I put a Select box with a list of entities. For this Select I query Database with partial, like this:

   ->select('partial c.{id, name}')
2. Later in the site I put a form to edit an entity. It is the one of those entities above. So I query DB for this entity (whole, not partial) and put it in the form.

The problem is that if I edit one of these entities, doctrine don't query it again to get all fields cause I already queried for it before.

Any idea how to resolve this? I don't want to query full entities for Select box.

Comment: Just do `$em->refresh($entity);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple, all you have to do is to refresh the entity to fetch it again from database:

```
$em->refresh($entity);
```